# What's difference "modifier" and "Modifier" (Kotlin Android, Jetpack Compose)

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

code ref: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kw4_i4l5y4s&ab_channel=PhilippLackner

I have two questions about this codes

```
@Composable
fun ProfileSection(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
        Row(
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(horizontal = 20.dp)
        ){
            RoundImage(
                image = painterResource(id = R.drawable.messi1),
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(100.dp)
                    .weight(3f)
            )
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(16.dp))
            StatSection(modifier = Modifier.weight(7f))
        }
    }
}
```

[ line 3 ] first is why use 'modifier: Modifier = Modifier'? what exactly it works?

[ line 5 ] second is what's difference "m"odifier and "M"odifier? when changing Modifier to modifier, code error(red underline) isn't occur. and result is not I want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You understand `int: Int = 0`? It is the same as that. The first **int** is our name (it can be anything we want). The second **Int** after the colon is our type, the kind of data we want the **int** to hold. The third is the value, **0** in this case.

**modifier** is the name of the parameter, **Modifier** is the type, and **Modifier** is the value. Now you may be getting confused by the fact that *Modifier* is an object itself of the type *Modifier*, but don't stress about it. It is a companion object, so you can use it both as an object type, and the object itself.

Also, since you see, Kotlin can infer the type based on the provided value, you can even skip the type here. For example, in `var int: Int = 0`, the **Int** is redundant. Kotlin will know that the type is `Int` because we are already assigning a value of that type (0, is Integer). So, we can just write it down as: `var int = 0`.

However, this is not the case with arguments, that is, if the entity in concern is a parameter of a function, you still must specify the type, even if you assign a value.

Hence, in your example,

```
fun ProfileSection(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) { ... }
```

Comment: But what's the purpose of "modifier: Modifier = Modifier"? Since I can use Modifier.xxx any time any where, why I need to define a "modifier", not just used the "Modifier"?

Comment: Hmm, you see hon', this **modifier** over here is provided as a parameter so that the caller of this Composable may also pass its own modifications per it's needs, for example, the calling site may have this call `ProfileSection(modifier = Modifier.height(500.dp).width(1000.dp)`.

Comment: Here's the proper breakdown. the word *modifier* is the name of the parameter which can be anything you want, but by convention, we always name it just that - modifier. The *Modifier* after the colon (:) is to specify the type of the argument, which is compulsory in case of parameters, the *Modifier* after the 'equals' sign is just to specify a default value of the parameter.

Comment: Here's how Kotlin works - If you create a parameter in a function, first of all, you must always specify the type of the parameter by specifying colons, and then if you want the parameter to be COMPULSORY to be fed in during the time of calling, you leave it just like that - a name and a type. HOWEVER, if you want to be able to handle the case where the calling site does not explicitly specify the parameter, you provide a DEFAULT value to the parameter, in this case, `modifier: Modifier = Modifier`, where `Modifier` is your default value.

Comment: Now, you can also call the Composable like this `ProfileSection(/*No Need to Specify a Modifier, the default one will be taken*/)`. If you want to make Modifications nonetheless, you can just go about and specify a modifier explicitly like `ProfileSection(modifier = Modifier.height(500.dp).width(1000.dp)` as I mentioned earlier.

Comment: Listen, I would recommend you please ask this as a separate question so I could just copy all these comments into a single answer. You see comments are specific to a single person. Now, if somebody else has this same doubt and they search StackOverflow, they would not be pointed to these comments since these belong under a different question. Since I've taken all this time to explain in detail, I would like it to help as many people as it should. Kindly create a separate question, stating something like "What is the purpose of the modifier parameter defined in Composable Definitions?"